# One liner to uppercase first letter?

Tags: bash, case-sensitive

I'm curious if there is a easier, short way to do this?

```
foo="FOO"
foo="${foo,,}"
echo "${foo^}" //Foo

bar="bar"
bar="${bar,,}"
echo "${bar^}" //Bar
```

The first part is important as I could use the carat to capitalize the first letter, but if the word is all caps, this does not lowercase the remainder. Thanks

Comment: Your solution is very good: it's pure Bash and easy to read. Why are you so concerned about a one-liner to do this? Actually, if you want a one liner, just write on one line: `foo="FOO"; foo="${foo,,}"; echo "${foo^}"`. And it has less keystrokes than the solution you accepted (and the solution you accepted forks an external program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this through sed,

```
foo="FOO";sed 's/.*/\L&/;s/^./\U&/' <<< "$foo"
```

Comment: Ouch lightening quick! Plus one and waiting for it to let me accept. Well done sir, exactly what I was after!

Comment: reversing of your's age will give mine. So please don't call me sir. Glad it worked out. You're always welcome..

Comment: Touche, glad to know we have a next generation of capable coders than ;)

Comment: @anubhava Agreed, fortunetly I'm using Debian systems all around.